# How can I make a horizontal sliding calendar in android eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, calendar, sliding

Hw to make a horizontal sliding calendar in android eclipse? Something like the image below:

[image]

Comment: HAd you got any solution for this .. please help me out for this please

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities

1.Create own customize calendar by customize view.

refer this - https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

2.Similar 3rd party available in github.

https://github.com/Mulham-Raee/Horizontal-Calendar/tree/18b8f1e27b681fa5005048efa2103261f8eaafc5

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### You can have a look at this code,
Just clone the repository and customize as per your need without any library

> https://github.com/Tejas-Soni/HorizontalCalendarAndroid

[image]