# android Calendar : how can i make an horizontal calendar ?

Tags: android, calendar

i search how to set an horizontal calendar like this picture : [image: Horizontal Calendar]

Comment: I think you need to use custom view. Or for example custom Recycler View with horizontal LinearLayoutManager. Please have a dig to this area and then, please, specify your question because it currently is to wide

Comment: **Check this link for proper answer**
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67207836/8572350)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your might want to look at [KBCalendar](https://github.com/Kevin-Bernage/KBCalendar-Android). With little modification you can give it your desired look.